# Css navigation not displaying with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I'm using javascript for my responsive navigation (working mobile first). When at 600px I use a media query to hide the 'Menu button', but the main Navigation should be still displayed, which it is not happening. I tried using a javascript to prevent it but it does not to work

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XxPgG/)

When dragging the screen bigger, the navigation is completly removed, which should not be happening

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#" id="logo">Logo</a>
        <div id="toggleNavMain">Menü</div>
        <nav>
            <ul id="navMain">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div><!--container-->
</header>
```

Javascript used

```
$(function() {
    var pull        = $('#toggleNavMain');
        menu        = $('#navMain');
        menuHeight  = menu.height();

    $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle('fast');
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
});
```

Css

```
.container {
    max-width: 1070px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    background-color: #FFCCCC;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#logo {
    background:url(http://placehold.it/220x80) 0 0 no-repeat;
    height: 80px;
    display: block;
    width: 220px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

#toggleNavMain {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 40px;
    background: #e3bf91;
    padding: 2% 3%;
    font-size:1.2em;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#navMain {display:none;}

#navMain {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

#navMain li {
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    width:100%; 
    margin-bottom:1%;
    background-color: blue;
}

#navMain li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 2% 0;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 600px) { 

#toggleNavMain {display:none;}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use an additional media query to hide the menu `ul` if the screen size is less than `600px`

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9d3F8/)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #navMain {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't that be considered bad practice - using two different types of media queries ('max' and 'min')? I'm fairly new to webdesign so excuse me if this question is kinda stupid.

Comment: @user2488493 I don't see how it would be considered a bad practice, they are being used properly. There are 2 media queries, neither of which will overlay, therefore one will always be satisfied. It's extremely common to have multiple media queries. If anything, it would be best to use an additional media query as opposed to adding more jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/XxPgG/1/

I think this is what you want.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
        menu.removeAttr('style');
    }
    if(w > 599) {
        menu.show();
    }
});
```